# Howto cast MutableLiveData<Boolean> as straight Boolean for a branch?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

In kotlin I have a function that returns MutableLiveData of type Boolean

```
fun getlightOn(): MutableLiveData<Boolean> {
    return lightOn
}
```

Elsewhere I need this value in an branch statement,

```
    val light = viewModel.getlightOn()
    if (light) {
        cameraManager.setTorchMode(cameraID, true)
    }
```

But am getting a mismatch on the (light), how can i cast the MutableLiveData type to plain old boolean ?

Comment: You should observe LiveData not accessing value directly, if you wana plain boolean(and don't care about changes) the use plain boolean in vm

Comment: There are sometimes scenarios where you could need to check current value (as opposed to observing which you typically would want alongside that)....in that case just use `light.value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify your function:

```
fun getlightOn(): Boolean? {
    return lightOn.value
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it should be `Boolean?` as value of LiveData can be null

Answer (score 2):

As Selvin and John O'Reilly pointed out in comments, LiveData should be observed, for example:

```
viewModel.lightOn.observe(viewLifecycleOwner,
        Observer { lightOn ->
            if (lightOn == null) {
                return@Observer
            }
            if (lightOn) {
                cameraManager.setTorchMode(cameraID, true)
            }
        })
```

Besides that if you want you original approach, a nullable return type must be used (as also commented by Selvin).

```
fun getlightOn(): Boolean? {
    return lightOn.value
}
```